# Trying to run 2 macros if cell has value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add to my existing working macro.  The upper part of this macro just makes some cells uppercase. The last line is for sorting dynamically.  Now I'd like to add functionality to only sort if column Q of the changed cell has a value.

In my mind the addition would be something like **If $Q <>"" then, *followed by sorting***

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    If Not Intersect(Range("i2:n1000,r2:aa1000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rng In Intersect(Range("j2:o1000,r2:aa1000"), Target)
            rng.Value = UCase(rng.Value)
        Next rng
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
   Range("g1").Sort Key1:=Range("g2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibe solution. I assume that you want to check the value in the column Q in the row of the selected cell (TARGET).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Q_Cell as Range

'Set the cell in the column "Q"

    Set Q_Cell = Range("Q" & Target.Row)

    If Not Intersect(Range("i2:n1000,r2:aa1000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rng In Intersect(Range("j2:o1000,r2:aa1000"), Target)
            rng.Value = UCase(rng.Value)
        Next rng
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If

'Check whether there is something in the cell or not. Using VBA.Len is quicker then testing against an empty string (e.g. Q_Cell <> "").

    If VBA.Len(Q_Cell.Value) <> 0 then

'If there is something in Q_Cell then sort the given range

        Range("g1").Sort Key1:=Range("g2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, That seems to work.